# How do I create a multi-level softlink in Linux or can this be done?

Tags: linux, unix, symlink

I have inherited old scripts which cannot be touched - don't ask.  It references software installed at location `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft/`

The new version of the software, remade since the buyout, installs at location 
`/usr/local/SomeSoft`

I've been having a bear trying to create the following softlink at the root level:

`ln -s SuperSoft/SomeSoft/ /usr/local/SomeSoft/`

I would hate to create a `SuperSoft` directory at the root level.  Can this be done?

Comment: If you are avoiding creating `/SuperSoft`, then I assume that `/usr/local/SomeSoft` is the existing directory, and `/SuperSoft/Somesoft` is the one you don't have (or am I misunderstanding?). Then you have the parameters on `ln -s` swapped around since the existing path is first, and the new path second. Also, I tried using ln on a 2-level uncreated path and it doesn't work. How about if you did `ln -s /usr/local /SuperSoft`? That would do it I think, except you'd also be able to access `/usr/local` from `/SuperSoft` (not sure if that's an undesirable side effect).

Answer (score 1):

Was hard to get want you want. Use this link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/SuperSoft/ /SuperSoft/
```

Now you can use the following `ls` to browse the contents of `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft`:

```
ls -al /SuperSoft/SomeSoft
```

Comment: They both added the link within the /usr/local/SomeSoft/ directory pointing to /SuperSoft/SomeSoft

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you wan't?

Comment: Ok, I guess you want the link placed in `/usr/local/` , yes? Then use `ln -s /SuperSoft/SomeSoft/ /usr/local`

Comment: They both produced the same result.  The both placed the link in the `/usr/local` directory.  I would like the link to be created at the root level and then point to the software in `/usr/local/SomeSoft`.  But in all cases I got a link `/usr/local/SomeSoft/SomeSoft->/SuperSoft/SomeSoft` instead of `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft->/usr/local/SomeSoft`

Comment: Damn! Why don't you tell that? Just switch the params.. Will update the answer

Comment: The first parameter is the actual location. The second parameter is the link. See my comment on the original post.

Comment: Yes this I know, but that doesn't work. I've tried many ways. I get `creating symbolic link '/SuperSoft/SomeSoft to /usr/local/SomeSoft/': No such file or directory`

Comment: That's why I suggested creating the link one level up. You can't do multiple levels. So `ln -s /usr/local /SuperSoft` might be the best you can do if you want to avoid creating a real directory `/SuperSoft`.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same files in two parts of the filesystem can also be accomplished with mount.

From "man mount" on linux:

> ```
>           Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount  part  of  the  file
>           hierarchy somewhere else. The call is
>                  mount --bind olddir newdir
>           or shortoption
>                  mount -B olddir newdir
>           or fstab entry is:
>                  /olddir /newdir none bind
>
>           After  this  call the same contents is accessible in two places.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the first form of `ln`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
```

Using `-s` as an option, since you want a symbolic link.  The `TARGET` is the "value" of the symlink--i.e., what the link is going to be pointing to.  The `LINK_NAME` is the actual location of the link being created.  So, to create a symlink at `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft` that points to `/usr/local/SomeSoft`, you would do:

```
ln -s /usr/local/SomeSoft /SuperSoft/SomeSoft
```

Which would look like this in a long listing:

```
$ ls -l /SuperSoft/SomeSoft
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 18 May 23 13:43 /SuperSoft/SomeSoft -> /usr/local/SomeSoft
```

So you can install the new version of your software as normal to `/usr/local`, and your existing scripts which cannot be modified will be pointed to `/usr/local` when they try to access `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft`.

Note that doing it this way assumes there exists a directory called `/SuperSoft`.  If this isn't an option for you (or if you just don't want to do it), then you can create a symlink at `/SuperSoft` that points to `/usr/local` (`ln -s /usr/local /SuperSoft`), since accessing `/Supersoft/SomeSoft` will turn into `/usr/local/SomeSoft`.  I'd recommend against this though, as it's not very clean.

UPDATE:

Another way to make it so that `/SuperSoft` is a symlink is to do:

```
mkdir /usr/local/SuperSoft
ln -s /usr/local/SuperSoft /SuperSoft
ln -s /usr/local/SomeSoft /SuperSoft/SomeSoft
```

In any case, there needs to be a directory that houses the link pointing to `/user/local/SomeSoft`.

Comment: I still get the same error - `No such file or directory` much like hek2mgl's suggestion.  I don't believe there is a way to do this without creating a top-level `/SuperSoft` directory.  I guess that's just the way I'll go and create a link in there.

Comment: You can do it without creating the top level directory if you do the ln at one level up: `ln -s /usr/local /SuperSoft`. Then `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft` will be the same as `/usr/local/SomeSoft`. Did you try that? Or is there a reason you can't?

Comment: @jnbbender like i said in my last paragraph, the directory `/SuperSoft` needs to exist in order to create the symlink `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft`.  if you want `/SuperSoft` to be the symlink, then one option is to have it point to `/usr/local` so that `/SuperSoft/SomeSoft` will hit `/user/local/SomeSoft`.  Or, you could create the directory `/usr/local/SuperSoft` and then do `ln -s /usr/local/SuperSoft /SuperSoft` and then `ln -s /usr/local/SomeSoft /SuperSoft/SomeSoft`.  i've updated my answer with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create a symlink that is a directory path.  A symlink is just an entry in an ordinary directory, so it must conform to all regular naming rules.

If you want a symlink "/SuperSoft/SomeSoft", then "/SuperSoft" *must* exist.  It could be a directory, or it could be a symlink to elsewhere, but it has to be something.

If you absolutely want to avoid creating a new directory in /, then you could create a fake / with the appropriate directories/symlinks/etc and run the scripts chrooted() there.  But that's a bunch more setup than just making one directory.